# w3 validator gives my navigation errors

Tags: php, mysql, navigation

I've been doing some researching and discovered this nice website http://validator.w3.org/

After running a test i see that my navigation get loads of error.

The error i get is the ul in the coding. I don't close it off because i give it it styling if a condition is met else close it. 
But this is not a valid solution according to w3 which gives me some errors.

Can you help me find a fix for my navigation so it gets valid?

With thanks Jim

```
<ul id="nav-container">
    <?php

    $select_category = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE hidden = 0 ORDER BY menu ASC");
    while ($ln = mysql_fetch_array($select_category)) {
        $idcat = $ln['nmr'];
        $catname = $ln['menu'];
        $catsname = str_replace(' ', '-', $ln['menu']);

        echo '<li>';
        if($catname == "carparts") {
            echo '<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/carparts.php" title="'.$catname.'"><span><strong>'.$catname.'</strong></span></a>';
        } else {
            echo '<a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/'.$idcat.'/'.$catsname.'/" title="'.$catname.'"><span><strong>'.$catname.'</strong></span></a>';
        }
```

This gives me the errors: (fixed)

```
echo '<ul';

if(isset($_GET['cats'])) {
    if ($_GET['cats'] == $idcat) {
        echo ' style="display:block;">';
    } else {
        echo '>';
    }
```

The fix: also deleted the closing bracket at the end.

```
echo '<ul';

if(isset($_GET['cats']) && $_GET['cats'] == $idcat){
    echo ' style="display:block;">';
} else {
    echo '>';
}
```

/fix finish

//Error finish

```
$select_sub = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submenu WHERE nmrmenu = '$idcat' AND hidden = 0");
while ($lsub = mysql_fetch_array($select_sub)) {
    $subname = $lsub['submenu'];
    $subsname = str_replace(' ', '-', $lsub['submenu']);
    $pil = '&raquo;';
    $brnr = $lsub['nmr'];

    if(isset($_GET['cat'])) {
        if ($_GET['cat'] == $brnr) {
            $subname = '<u>'.$lsub['submenu'].'</u>';
        } else {
            $subname = $lsub['submenu'];
        }
    }

    echo '<li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/'.$lsub['nmr'].'/'.$subsname.'/"><span><strong> '.$subname.' </strong></span></a></li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
echo '</li>'; // to this location
}
  echo '</li>'; //relocated this up one line
} **//Deleted this one!** 

?>
</ul>
```

**Update**
The output gets like this which is horrible: (fixed)

```
<ul</li><li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/x/name/" title="name"><span><strong>name</strong></span></a>

<ul</li><li><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/x/name/" title="name"><span><strong>name</strong></span></a><ul</li>
```

**New:** now the ul problem is gone, but it's complaining about the li's. Any clue why?

Error: document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag

```
<ul id="nav-container">
    <li>
        <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/x/name/" title="name"><span><strong>name</strong></span></a>

        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/x/name/"><span><strong> name </strong></span></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**/update**

Comment: We only need to see the final HTML as that is what is validated

Comment: Are you passing the php into the validator, or the final html?

Comment: @WayneC I pass the index.php into the validator, I've fixed about all errors, what remains is the navigation menu as shown above. I will update the question with two lines of code from the HTML

Comment: @JohnConde I pass the index.php into the validator, I've fixed about all errors, what remains is the navigation menu as shown above. I will update the question with two lines of code from the HTML

Comment: You need to validate the result of running `index.php`, not the source code to `index.php`.

Comment: "it's complaining about the li's" — "It's complaining"? That doesn't tell us much. What complaint is it giving? You need to quote actual error messages. Errors are also often a matter of context, at a minimum you should show the parent element of the code that is causing the error.

Comment: @Quentin This is the error i get for each li: document type does not allow element "li" here; missing one of "ul", "ol", "menu", "dir" start-tag

Comment: *Line 28, Column 2176*?! It is a lot easier to debug code when you don't put it all on one line! Add some `\n`s to that!

Comment: @Quentin Strange, it echoes out my \n it doesn't put a new row.

Comment: @JimSundqvist — Don't use single quoted strings if you want escape characters to work in PHP.

Comment: @Quentin i ended up using . PHP_EOL now it should look neater

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `</ul>` and then immediately follow it with a `<li>`. You can't have a list item outside of a list.

Comment: I've tried multiple changes to the php but end up with the same error. i believe the error come from the ul that is outside of the php. It has to be inserted into the php so it echoes out for each row. Also as you say, the "parent" li doesn't close off but is entering a new ul which also have not been closed off yet. Any ideas what i could change? I've tried most of my ideas.

Comment: This document was successfully checked as XHTML 1.0 Transitional!